# T4 Templates - Generates Unit Test classes from the classes which implement an interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, templates, visual-studio-2012, t4

I have a large number of classes which all use the same interface. This is the first time this code will have unit tests so I'm trying to think of the best way to generate all of these tests, or the structure of the classes at least.

I know T4 Templates are used in EF to generate multiple files based on the model. Is there a way I can specify in the T4 Template that I want it to look at all of the classes which implement an interface and generate a unit test class for each. Alternatively, if it's easier, all of the classes are within the same folder so if I could just point it at that folder it would probably be fine.

Once that is done I can fill in the details of each unit test class with the specfics. I'd obviously have to remove the T4 file so it doesn't overwrite the code I've added to the classes, maybe there is a way to do that too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look a this blog post:

http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/blog/how-to-generate-multiple-output-files-from-a-single-t4-template.html

It should enable you to generate multiple outputs with a single .tt file. I use it in (almost) the same way you do, I generate a huge class of methods (3000 lines) based on an xml file and then I generate another file containing unit tests for those methods. Ironically, the unit tests pointed out several bugs in my big generated class, even though the unit tests were generated also.

Answer (score 0):

A T4 template always generates only one piece of output, be it one output file for the design time template or one string for the runtime template. The template itself will therefore not be able to generate you multiple files. Nonetheless, with a little code, you can use a single runtime template multiple times, to create multiple pieces of output as you like.

I suggest to create a simple utility, separate from the main project, which will contain the T4 runtime template and the code which will, for example, inspect a given assembly or bunch of given source files and generate the appropriate test skeleton using the T4 runtime template and save it to a file for each of the classes of interest. I guess it depends on the number of classes in question, if it is worth it to spend a little time to create such a tool.

If it's not clear enough, just let me know and I will try to provide an example.

Comment: Hi, I don't think that's correct. If you look at the EF context.tt file you'll see it generates a number of seperate files via - fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs"); . I appreciate your input though, I think I just need to work through the context file and learn from that.

Comment: @user1266921 What you mention is a EF specific functionality implemented via `EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager` class as documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477603.aspx. So if you don't mind the EF reference, using this could also be a solution. Or of course you can implement a similar thing yourself or use some other implementation. Still the out of the box behavior of the T4 is one output file with the same name as the the template and the extension specified by the <#@ output #> directive and the approach I proposed is IMHO the easiest way to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar in a new project, where I want to use a T4 template to generate some code that pertains to all the classes that inherit from a particular class.  (Basically write a factory generator class to create a new instance of each derived class given only a string containing the class name, and also to collect a list of the public properties in each class without using reflection at runtime.  That way, other developers can just add the new class to the project without worrying about tying it into our framework.)

I'm also keeping the source classes in a common subfolder.

While I'm only starting to design how the template works, the template will run before the code is compiled, so my process will be to:

1. For each source code file in the subfolder:

   1. Load the file into memory.
   2. Use regular expressions to verify the class in the file inherits from the desired base class.
   3. Use regular expressions to extract the data I need.
2. Write the output class using the data I've gathered (class names, public property names)

This is something where [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh500769.aspx) may be useful in analyzing the code in order to extract class and property names, but I'm not going to get too fancy just yet.  My approach will limit us to one class per file, and will only work with the one language we're writing in, but that's convention over configuration that we can live with.

You may find [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882448.aspx) useful, as well as [Oleg Sych's blog and toolkit](http://www.olegsych.com/).  Oleg's T4 Toolbox includes a template for generating multiple output files from a single T4 template.